# Flutter variable (getter) is always null when called in a different class

Tags: flutter, dart, stacked

I have set up my architecture using view=>viewmodel=>services.

In the `FirestoreServices()` class, I have retrieved the loggedin user's data and stored it in a variable `_currentUser()` to access it from any location within the app. Here is the code that performs this action:

```
 Future getUser(String userId) async {
    try {
      DocumentSnapshot snapshot =
          await _usersCollectionReference.doc(userId).get();

      Object? data = snapshot.data();
      var userObjectAsString = (data as Map<String, dynamic>);

      return UserModel.fromData(userObjectAsString);
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
      return e.message;
    }
  }
```

The returned value is available in my `AuthenticationServices()` class where I set it to a private variable _currentUser and create the getter.

```
...
  UserModel? _currentUser;
  UserModel? get currentUser => _currentUser;
...
 
 Future _populateCurrentUser(User? user) async {
    if (user != null) {
      _currentUser = await _firestoreService!.getUser(user.uid);
    }
  }
```

The problem is that when I attempt to access this variable in the `MarketViewModel()` through the getter, the value is always null:

```
  String? _displayName;

  set displayName(String? _displayName) {
    _displayName = _authenticationService.currentUser!.fullName;
    
  }

  String? get displayName => _displayName;
```

The UserModel() class holds a map of the user:

```
class UserModel {
  final String? fullName;
  final String? id;
  final String? email;
  final String? phoneNumber;
  UserModel({this.email, this.fullName, this.id, this.phoneNumber});

  UserModel.fromData(Map<String, dynamic> data)
      : id = data['id'],
        fullName = data['fullName'],
        email = data['email'],
        phoneNumber = data['phoneNuber'];

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'fullName': fullName,
      'email': email,
      'phoneNumber': phoneNumber,
      'id': id,
    };
  }
}
```

Why isn't the `MarketViewModel()` receiving the populated currentUser?

EDIT:
Signup()

```
`UserModel? _currentUser;

  UserModel? get currentUser => _currentUser;

  Future signUp(
      {required String fullName,
      required String email,
      required String phoneNumber,
      required String password}) async {
    try {
      var authResult = await _firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);

      _currentUser = UserModel(
        id: authResult.user!.uid,
        email: email,
        fullName: fullName,
      );

      await _firestoreService!.createUserRecord(_currentUser!);
      print(_currentUser);
      return authResult.user != null;
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      return e.message;
    }
  }`
```

EDIT:
Login()

```
`Future logIn({required email, required password}) async {
    try {
      var authResult = await _firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);

      await _populateCurrentUser(authResult.user!);

      return authResult.user;
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      return e.message;
    }
  }
```

EDIT:
isUserLoggedIn()

```
 ` isUserLoggedIn() {
    var user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    _populateCurrentUser(user);
    return user;
  }
}`
```

Comment: where are calling `_populateCurrentUser` this method ?

Comment: I am calling it on `createUser()`, `login()` and `isUserLoggedIn()`.

Comment: can you please post that code line too (anyone of above) where you calling it?

Comment: Sure thing. Just added the edits.

Comment: Coud you also add the code for your ``AuthenticationServices`` class?

Comment: @Apps 247 Please see 3 edits i just made on the question. I marked them "EDIT". They make up my `AuthenticationServices` class

Comment: your login is not calling the populate user method, and isUserLogin calling the it without await keyword which means your code continue to running while the userPopulate method is still in progress in background whereas you are accessing the uninitialized variable at the same time. What do you think about it ?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have made the function await but I still don't receive the value. Also, my login() method does make a call to `_populateCurrentUser(authResult.user!)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this change:

```
UserModel? get currentUser => _firebaseAuth.currentUser;
```

*Note:* I have not used null safety in `_firebaseAuth.currentUser` as I am not familiar with it. Please add any null safety features to `_firebaseAuth.currentUser` if required.

Comment: This will connect with Firebase (in my viewModel) to request the currentUser and this is what I'm trying to avoid. All direct requests to firebaseAuth or Firestore are to be made in the services. The request to get currentUser has already been made in the Firestore service and the value is stored in the _currentUser variable so that I can access it anywhere without requesting it from Firebase directly. The issue here is that I am not successfully passing the stored value of _currentUser from the services to the viewModel. I hope this makes sense

Comment: I'm sorry I'm a bit confused about how you are assigning a value to _currentUser, it seems that it isn't initialized. Could you show or send a link to the complete code of your AuthenticationServices without cutting out the initialization etc.?

Comment: I did manage to get it working by changing the setter and getterr in the MareketModel to a full function and calling that from the UI. But all the same, here's a link to all of the code involved in this problem:
https://github.com/corporate-cas/viewCodeForTest/blob/da74cd052c49970ba07c432b2b9418c6ee7e6874/fable_issues

Comment: @LazySingleton()
class AuthenticationService {
  final FirestoreService? _firestoreService = locator<FirestoreService>();
  final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  UserModel? _currentUser;
  UserModel? get currentUser => _currentUser; // You are getting ``currentUser`` here. At this point, ``_currentUser`` has not been assigned yet, so is null. ``currentUser`` returns ``_currentUser``, which is null.

Comment: I see! So I need to set first and allow the variable to get populated *before I use the getter? Great, I'll try this out.